# Robot Framework: How to read a random row in a csv files and use the values?

Tags: python, csv, robotframework

I made this code in python:

```
import csv

import random

class RandomRowFromCsv (object):

    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'Global'

    def __init__(self):
            print 'Read Random Cell Value in CSV File'

    def read_random_row(self,filename):
            csv_userinfo=[]
            auserinfo={}
            with open(filename,'rb') as csvfile:
                    reader=csv.DictReader(csvfile)

                    csv_userinfo=list(reader)

                    lengthofcsv=len(csv_userinfo)
                    position=random.randrange(1,lengthofcsv)

                    auserinfo=RandomRowFromCsv(*csv_userinfo[position])

                    return auserinfo.username
                    return auserinfo.password
```

But i can't get the values and make a script in Robot Framework to get them values, someone can help me?

Comment: do you get error message ? show full error message (Traceback) in question. You use `RandomRowFromCsv(argument)` with arguments but you declare `__init__(self)` without arguments. How do you execute `read_random_row()` ? `return` always leaves function so second `return` will never use (`return auserinfo.password`)

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'username' @furas

Comment: show full error message (Traceback) in question. see words "full" and "in question" !

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Workspaces\RobotFramework_AndreGoncalves\RandomRowFromCsv.py", line 63, in <module>
    print auserinfo.username
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'username' @furas

Comment: show full error message (Traceback) in question. see words "in question" , not in comment ! You can edit question and add this in question (and format) to make it more readable. BTW: you should add this error message at start because it is very important information.

Comment: BTW: you have problem in line 63 with `print auserinfo.username` but I don't see this line in your question :)  Problem is: `auserinfo` is list, not class so you can't use  `.username` as you could do with class.

Comment: Well I try to solve the problem this way:

http://dontpad.com/randomrowcodepy

but I'm having a problem again...
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    new_info = info.read_random_row('UserInfo.csv')
  File "RandomRowLibrary.py", line 13, in read_random_row
    logs=RandomRowLibrary(*rows[position])
TypeError: object() takes no parameters**

@furas

Comment: this error everyone sees in question - and see my first comment. You use `RandomRowFromCsv(*csv_userinfo[position])` with arguments but you declare `__init__(self)` in `class RandomRowFromCsv` without arguments.

Comment: Ok it's working, problem solved !
Thank you @furas

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
auserinfo = RandomRowFromCsv(*csv_userinfo[position])
```

You are creating a new `RandomRowFromCsv` object (a circular reference), which **a)** you don't need, and **b)** the class'es constructor doesn't accept arguments (if **a)** was not applicable).

As by that line you've already parsed the csv file and have it in the `userinfo` list, you just need to assign the row to the `auserinfo`:

```
auserinfo = csv_userinfo[position]
```

Now `auserinfo` is a dict; to get the name & the password, you should use `aserinfo['username']` (where "username" is the csv column name). The dot notation will not work - it's for objects attributes, which is not the case here.

And to return both simultaneously, return them as a tuple - change the last two lines to:

```
return aserinfo['username'], aserinfo['password']
```

Finally, you have a small logical flow - due to the `1` in

```
position = random.randrange(1, lengthofcsv)
```

, the first row will never be selected - `position` will never have the value 0, which is the index of the 1st row; so it's better to change the `randrange` argument to `0`.